# Truncate an string to size in a PCRE

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

Using a single regex line (this goes in a config file for an application) I need to capture the localpart of an email address.

If it consists of only numbers, pass it along unmodified.
If it has any non-numeric character on it, truncate to 11 chars max.

I made this simple program to test but if the localpart is over 11 characters there is no match (the whole email address is printed).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

my @emails = ('the-chuck.t1.norrisson@chuck.com', '358451399991@chucksphon.com', 'ph33t@gmail.com', 'the-average.guyisbald@example.com', 'alongnameit@11chars.com', 'alongnameitis@13chars.com', 'a1234567890@11charnum.com');

for my $email (@emails){

    # will put $1$2 on the substituion spot
    $email =~ s/^(\d+)@.+|^([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]{1,11})@.+/  /;

    print '===> ' . $email  . " \n\n ";

}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include a regex atom such as `\S*?` in case the number of  characters exceeds 11...

```
    $email =~ s/^(\d+)@.+|^([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]{1,11})\S*?@.+/$1$2/;
```

Using this produces correct output:

```
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ perl sample.pl
===> the-chuck.t

 ===> 358451399991

 ===> ph33t

 ===> the-average

 ===> alongnameit

 ===> alongnameit

 ===> a1234567890

 [mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$
```